# Segmentation fault in a function to reverse a singly linked list recursivley

Tags: c, data-structures, recursion, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I am implementing a function to recursively reverse a linked-list, but getting seg-fault.

```
typedef struct _node {
   int data;
   struct _node *next;
} Node, *NodeP;

NodeP recursiveReverseList(NodeP first){
   if(first == NULL) return NULL;
   if(first->next == NULL) return first;

   NodeP rest = recursiveReverseList(first->next);
   rest->next = first;
   first->next = NULL;

   return first;
}
```

Can you please help?

P.S. The iterative version is working fine though. Its not homework. Just practicing C.

Thank you all :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Unicornaddict has already posted a correct algorithm.

But, if you are still getting `segmentation fault`, I suspect you are making some mistake in calling the function from `main`.

#### Correct:

```
head->next = recursiveReverseList(head->next);
```

#### Explanation:

- Pass `head->next` to the recursive function. If you pass `head`, it will do something like

> *Before call:*
>    **head ---> A ---> B ---> C**
>   *After call:*
>    **head <--- A <--- B <--- C**

which will make `head` point to `NULL` and `A` point to `head`

- After passing `head->next` as argument, state of the list is:

> **head ---> A <--- B <--- C**

So, you need to make `head` point to `rest` (`C` in this case).

Comment: @nvl: thanks. i was just calling `recursiveReverseList(head)`. It works now with expected output.

Answer (score 5):

The general recursive algorithm for this is:

1. `Divide` the list in `2` parts - first
   node and rest of the list.
2. Recursively call reverse for the `rest` of the
   linked list.
3. Link `rest` to `first`.
4. Fix `head` pointer

You are doing steps 1 and 2 correctly but I guess you've messed up in steps 3 and 4. I would suggest you try this:

```
NodeP recursiveReverseList(NodeP first){
   if(first == NULL) return NULL; // list does not exist.
   if(first->next == NULL) return first; // list with only one node.

   NodeP rest = recursiveReverseList(first->next); // recursive call on rest.
   //rest->next = first; CHANGE THIS
   first->next->next = first; // make first next to the last node in the reversed rest.

   first->next = NULL; // since first is the new last..make its next NULL.

   //return first; CHANGE THIS
   return rest; // rest now points to the head of the reversed list.
}
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [geeksforgeeks.org](http://geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/Linked-List-Rverse.gif))</sub>
.

**EDIT:**

<s>PS: I've not tested this. So try it and let us know :)</s>

I've tested the above function and seems to work as expected. You can try the program here:
http://ideone.com/bQXAV

Comment: @Amanda: I see no problems. Lets wait. Maybe someone might catch the bug :) Meanwhile where exactly are you getting SEGV? Show us the stack trace if possible.

Comment: @Amanda: I tested the function and it works fine for me. I've updated the bug with the link to the program. The stack trace of the program can be gotten by using a debugger like gdb. More on that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/966428/how-do-you-use-gdb

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm seems to be wrong. You need to return the pointer to the head of the new list, but you are returning the pointer to the last item.

Indeed, you perhaps need both of them: a pointer to the head and the pointer to the last item.

Comment: pointer to last item, because after the function returns, i have to assign `last_item->next`

Answer (score 0):

i think

```
rest->next = first;
```

should be

```
first->next->next = first;
```

Comment: Hmm..I think when you recursively call reverse on rest of the list, rest will be pointing to the **start** of the **reversed** rest-list. So its next->next would not make sense.