# linked list reverse without temp

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

Is there any way to reverse linked list without using temp variable in C?
Thanks in advance.

the famous approach:

```
Element *reverse(Element *head)
{
    Element *previous = NULL;

    while (head != NULL) {
        // Keep next node since we trash
        // the next pointer.
        Element *next = head->next;

        // Switch the next pointer
        // to point backwards.
        head->next = previous;

        // Move both pointers forward.
        previous = head;
        head = next;
    }

    return previous;
}
```

uses temp variable

Saurabh

Comment: Recursion is a cheat since the parameters are essentially temporary variables.

Comment: Agreed, but that's usually the kind of semantic quibbling questions like this one are all about.

Comment: That's the kind of semantic quibbing used by participants that aren't aware of the real answer. :P

Comment: Would you please tell me the recursive way.

Comment: There are a couple questions similar to that already out there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078864/reversing-linked-list and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621077/segmentation-fault-in-a-function-to-reverse-a-singly-linked-list-recursivley for example... Those do use a temp variable, but they may give you something to start with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that your `temp` usage is actually generating two `swap()` calls, and can be replaced with:

```
swap(head->next,previous);
swap(previous,head);
```

You can swap without temps using xor, it is called [xor swap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm).

Answer (score 3):

Use [XOR-swaps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm) on the pointers to fake an [XOR-linked-list.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_linked_list)

*Implementation is left to the reader as an exercise.*

Answer (score 1):

Recursive approach :

```
Element *reverse(Element *head, Element **first)
{
    if (head->next == NULL)
    {
        *first = head;
        return head;
    }


     Element* NextElement= reverse  (head->next, first);
     NextElement->next = head;
     head->next = null;

     return head;
}
```

Call for recursive function:

```
   Element *revLinkListHead;
   reverse(head, &revLinkListHead);
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still interested, here is the solution that uses no new variables at all, except for those passed in recursive call.

```
public static List invert(List l) {
    invert(l.next, l, l);
    l = l.next;
    breakCycle(l, l);
    return l;
}

private static void invert(List l, List toBeNext, List first) {
    if(l.next == null) {
        l.next = toBeNext;
        first.next = l;
    } else {
        invert(l.next, l, first);
        l.next = toBeNext;
    }
}

private static void breakCycle(List l, List first) {
    if(l.next == first) {
        l.next = null;
    } else {
        breakCycle(l.next, first);
    }
}
```

The idea is the following: first we run invert function recursively, and implement it so that when it reaches the last element it assigns it as a next element of current head (parameter `first`). After we executed it, we will have a reversed list but cycled, so the current head.next will point at the head of the reversed list. We reassign  head to its next element (the actual head of the reversed list), and the last thing we have to do is to break the cycle. So we call `breakCycle` which does the job recursively!