# "Ej4.exe has stopped working" – How to use a debugger?

Tags: c, debugging, codeblocks

When compiling the following program appears "Ej4.exe has stopped working". Can I find the error with a debugger? I have never used this and would like to know in which cases it is used and how.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 100

int findMaxElem(int []);

int main(){
    int arr1[MAX],mxelem,i,n;

    printf(" Ingrese el numero de elementos a almacenar en el arreglo :");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    printf(" Ingrese %d elementos en el arreglo:\n",n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf(" elemento - %d : ",i);
        scanf("%d",&arr1[i]);
    }
    mxelem=findMaxElem(arr1);

    printf(" El maximo elemento en el arreglo es: %d\n\n",mxelem);
    return 0;

}


int findMaxElem(int arr1[])
{
    int i=1,mxelem,n;
    mxelem=arr1[0];
    while(i < n)
    {
        if(mxelem<arr1[i])
        mxelem=arr1[i];
        i++;
    }
    return mxelem;
}
```

Comment: Do other programs you write compile properly? If not, it could be a configuration issue, perhaps try using a different program to compile your code.

Comment: the `n` you use in `findMaxElem()` is never assigned to anything

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966428/how-do-you-use-gdb?s=14|77.2083 Does that help in the more general situation of learning to debug?

Answer (score 4):

In the other function `findMaxElem()` you have used `n` which is uninitialized. As a result you have undefined behavior - and that undefined behavior that made your program to stop. (Maybe the garbage value is making you access the out of bound array access). Here `n` is uninitialized. Pass the `n` from `main` to this function.

```
mxelem=findMaxElem(n,arr1);
```

and use it

```
int findMaxElem(int n, int arr1[])
{
   int i=1,mxelem;
   mxelem=arr1[0];
   while(i < n)
   {
      if(mxelem < arr1[i])
         mxelem = arr1[i];
      i++;
   }
   return mxelem;
}
```

---

#### How did I debug it?

```
>>gcc -g prog.c -o prog.x
>>gdb prog.x
(gdb) run

..
```

Then everyhting I run it returned me `0`-th element. Something is wrong. The most important function being `findMaxElem` I put a breakpoint there.

```
(gdb) break findMaxElem
...

(gdb) run
```

Now it stopped at that point after I got there (by that I meant after giving inputs).

```
Breakpoint 1, findMaxElem (arr1=0xbffff1e8) at prog.c:30
30          int i=1,mxelem,n;
(gdb) next
31          mxelem=arr1[0];
(gdb) print mxelem
$3 = 1  <-- for me first element entered was 1
(gdb) next
32          while(i < n)
(gdb) print i
$4 = 1
(gdb) print n
$5 = -2147475456 <---- this gave me the idea that it is the error over here.
(gdb)
```

---

So the answer is yes. You can use debugger to find out where the problem is. You didn't mention what debugger you have used but I have shown you a small debugging steps using `gdb`.